# How to add AndroidImageSlider library to my project

Tags: android

I want to add AndroidImageSlider library to my project

library link --> [click here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider)

but how can i do that?

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/releases/download/v1.0.9/AndroidImageSlider-Eclipse.zip) , just import it from file -> import -> Existing Project To Workspace , select your Project and Import . then in your project properties , android section , panel below android Api's, add that library to your project .

**Edit** : Steps to add a library Project to Existing Project :

1 - download Library Project File

2 - import that library to the eclipse file -> import -> Existing Project To Workspace -> Browse to your File

3 - if the IsLibrary tick marck doesn't have checked , check that to inform that project as a library project in Properties -> Android

4- inside your Main Project properties Android -> Library -> add -> your library project

** if the library project path has been changed you have update your main project reference to the new path  remove it again and add updated path to your library project.

Comment: thanks , but i do that an i have this problem [link](http://up.codfans.ir/uploads/140878133723311.png)

Comment: @alirezaamini : did you move the library folder? if so , remove the reference and add it again.the project library should be imported to eclipse before.

Comment: @alirezaamini : the project folder should be ticked as "is library" not your main project.as you see eclipse can't find proper path of your library.

Comment: Sorry but i cant understand i do the second step but it have that problem again what i have to do now please say it step by step

Comment: Oh thanks alot. i am so sorry about my question thank you again ممنون :D

Comment: Thanks. it helped me too